# Er diagram for online tractor service maintenance system

Tags: html, php

Project name, Online Tractor Maintenance System, Farmer can create account on online platform. Once farmer log in, they can assess the different features and functionality of the system. Farmer can input their tractor details such as model name, year of manufacture, model number. Farmer can set up maintenance schedule for their tractor. They can specify the tasks that need to be performed regularly like oil change, filter replacement, etc. The system allows them to set a frequency and duration for each task. Once the maintenance schedule is set, the system sends reminder and notification to farmer at the appropriate times. And the tractor needs to service in the system sends suggestions to mechanics or service center. Once farmer can decide to service their tractor and book the mechanic and what service is performed. Farmer can fix time and appointment to serve their tractor. Once the farmer has served their tractor, the system can automatically calculate the cost based on the service performed and part used. The bill format can include such as the farmer name, tractor details, service performed, service performed part used, labor charges, and the additional charges. The bill can also include the date of service, invoice number, and the total cost. When the bill is generated, it can be sent to the farmer mail or made available for the download through the system. In this my project, please give me the ER diagram, synopsis and my overall project details.

Comment: What does the last sentence mean?  What relevance do the tags have with the recommendation request?